# Nginx selects TLS version from another server

Tags: nginx

nginx.conf:

```
events {
}

http {
    server {
        server_name {domain};
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
        ssl_certificate {path}.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key {path}.pem;
        return 200 'Success';
    }

    server {
        server_name _;
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.1;
        ssl_certificate {path}.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key {path}.pem;
        return 404 'Domain not found';
    }
}
```

Output of `nginx -V`:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.16.1
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019 (running with OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019)
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: {snipped}
```

Output of `openssl version`:

```
OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
```

With this setup, visiting {domain} displays "Success" over a TLS 1.1 connection. Why in the world is Nginx doing that, and how can I make it stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the TLS is setup to include that protocol in the connector on port 443 as You configure that protocol on that ports connector. TLS is setup to allow v1.1 connections.
The choice of virtual host is only done based on server name.
To stop it You normally only enable tlsv1.2 and v1.3 for that port. The client then gets a proper SSL error that his protocols are not supported.
If You want to prevent the use of specific vhost if client does not offer 1.2 You can include a rewrite rule in the corresponding vhost that rewrites depending on value of variable `$ssl_protocol`. In that case You do not have a well behaving server because it completed handshake and afterwards returns error on application level. But it would do what You tried to do with Your above config.

I just found with OpenSSL 1.1.1 there is a functionality (SSL_CTX_set_client_hello_cb) that the (web)server could use to restrict TLS version depending on hostname.
However this is currenlty not implemented in nginx from what I can find.

Comment: If the protocol is per port, then why is it allowed as server-level config, and why does it always choose the second server's protocol? Swapping the two versions in the example results in a TLS 1.2 connection. And doesn't SNI let Nginx select a server before establishing a TLS connection?

Comment: The old SNI implementation doesn't really allow. The callbacks provided by OpenSSL (as example / default implementation) did not allow to adjust the SSL/TLS version anymore, thought SNI/ALPN allows it as the information is sent in client hello before the server needs to respond. This is my last sentence: in OpenSSL 1.1.1 there is a new function SSL_CTX_set_client_hello_cb which allows the application to install a callback that is called early enough to adjust this setting in the SSL context for that connection. this is not implemented in nginx till now.

Comment: For the other part it doesn't select the second servers protocol but configures the initial SSL context the listener using the default server for each defined ssl listening port (including certificate of default vhost, for example). After connection came in it sets all the ssl related options to the vhosts settings if ALPN/SNI is sent by client and a matching vhost is found. But at that stage with old callbacks OpenSSL wil ignore the protocol change. If one implements using the client_hello_cb instead of the older sni/alpn callbacks, this functionality will become available with current code.

Comment: Thank you. It's a shame Nginx doesn't document this.

Comment: It's just for consitency and Nginx tries to set it but OpenSSL does not honor. As a vhost can have a different listening port it must be definable in vhost. Of course there could be a check for this (so that it is only defined on the default vhost). And there is no need (but could be better documented). So as late as nginx implements client_hello_cb for new OpenSSL versions You can continue to use Your config and get the feature, but anyway Your default vhost which is generally documented as default (so for initial contact) must include all protocol versions You want to use within Your vhosts.

Comment: Yes nginx documentation is diffuclt. But it's very well documented, it's open-source ;-) And even OpenSSL itself does not document this issue good with the late running callbacks. So maybe nginx developer are just not aware, they try to set all settings from vhost. (But anyway I do not understand why to prefer nginx as long as the apache httpd is that fine it is until now ;-) )